# Should Providers be Multi-Sources or Configurations in configurable product?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, configurable-product, simple-product, multi-source-inventory

I have a store where

1. showing catalog from my vendors I don't have actual inventory
2. end-customer is not aware of my vendors (so it is not multi-vendor store)
3. currently, I am using the configurable product for all product info and simple-product(configration) that is linked to the configurable and has (cost, qty, price, and vendorID)
4. configrations are auto-selected based on cost so the customer does not select which product from which vendor because he is not aware of my vendors

Today I found this (multi-source-inventory-in-magento-2.3)
https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/multi-source-inventory-in-magento-2.html

and now I am confused did I did the wrong implementation?
I read about it but I am still confused

- how MSI handles different costs from different sources?
- how to handle different selling prices?

Answer (score 0):

Multi-source basically let you define sources and stocks for products.

Like, If you have SKU `ABC` you got different sources where that product actually stands. Total QTY of that product is `30` but for you `20` available in lets say in `warehouse-A` and `10` in **warehouse-B**

With Multi source inventory you can define that differentiate qty based on warehouses. so while shipping that product you'll get an option to choose from where you're shipping and all this manage within Magento Cool Isn't it !?

Regarding showing vendors MSI doesn't provide that option for now.

For more information you can go through below wiki.

https://github.com/magento/inventory/wiki

https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/inventory-merchant-type.html

Magento MSI doesn't provide update prices based on sources you need to customize at your own risk :P

Comment: Thanks, @anonymous. but my question is: can I use MSI for different cost & sale prices?

Comment: According to sources I read on the internet that it's not possible with default installation but you can retrieve qty based on sources rest of thing you need to customize.